# Node.js error: global module: ' command not found '

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, dependencies

**Solution:**

1. Permissions error - fixed with confidence from comment by *Kadir*
2. Bower Sourcing of bin - fixed with with clarity from *Josiah's* comment
3. sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local

.bower-profile

```
if [ -r ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
case "$-" in *i*) if [ -r ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi;; esac
```

.profile

```
PATH=~/npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

---

**Original Error Trail**

Mac OS X El Captain | Node v5.0 | NPM 3.4.0

npm works, global commands like git work.

`bower -g` in projects does not work.

```
Aarons-MacBook-Air:test2 Akorn$ ionic start todo blank
-bash: ionic: command not found
Aarons-MacBook-Air:test2 Akorn$ ionic --version
-bash: ionic: command not found
Aarons-MacBook-Air:test2 Akorn$ npm ionic -l -v
3.4.0
```

Permission Error

```
Aarons-MacBook-Air:test2 Akorn$ brew update && brew upgrade node
Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
software may change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the
"InstantOn" component of Airfoil are known to do this.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
Aarons-MacBook-Air:test2 Akorn$ brew --version
Homebrew 0.9.5 (git revision fb84; last commit 2015-12-22)
```

**Questions**
Can I trust sudo fixes?

Is there a better fix?

Are there methods for further diagnostics?

**How did I break this?**

1. Incorrectly updating npm or node - so however npm calls global functions from wrong folder.
2. Incorrectly using brew.
3. Ugly code in `.profile`/`.profile_bash`.

   `~/.bash_profile`:

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```

   `~/.profile`:

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

   [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
   ```

Comment: Did you notice that "Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable." line after running `brew` command? This should probably be related to a permission error. What permissions do you see on the **local** directory when you run `ls -l /usr`? and have you tried the recommendation that says you should run `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`

Comment: $ ls -l /usr > local reads 'root  wheel' then I ran the sudo code and now > local reads 'Akorn  Admin'   **bow **bow I was scared of sudo, but now I understand what this line executes

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you see `-bash: mycommand: command not found` it means that the command you're trying to use isn't located where bash is looking for it. Bash usually looks in the present working directory and in any location that's listed in the `$PATH` environment variable.

You can see what the current value of `$PATH` is by running `echo $PATH`. Judging based on the `~/.profile` contents you posted, the location you have `ionic` installed in is not part of your path. You'll have to verify where that file is installed; maybe `/Users/Akorn/npm-global/lib` or maybe there was a shortcut installed in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`, so you'll want to check those too and make sure that those are added to your `$PATH`. As an example, my `$PATH` looks like this; `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Josiah/docker/bin`

To learn how to add a new location to your `$PATH`, read up on [the first answer to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path).

Comment: $ echo $PATH
/Users/Akorn/npm-global/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Akorn/.rvm/bin **bow **bow your clarity has illuminated a dark corner.